# Ef core 2 diferent tables to same dto

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select, dto

I'm doing a select to an IQueryable, so this IQueryable can come from 2 different tables but the dto is the same. My problem is that I'm duplicating the code because of the select for each of them. Is there any way to create a general method that receives the IQueryable and inside it does the select?

Comment: That is what an interface is used for.  Your select is an interface into the class object.

Comment: You take that code, put it in a method, make an interface that specifies all those props on the *table* entity, make each different entity implement that interface, and then your method can take an object of type IWhatever

Comment: What about using an `IQueryable` extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an interface:

```
interface INamed{
  string Name {get; set;}
}
```

You have two different table entities that implement it because they both have a Name property:

```
public class Person : INamed {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Company: INamed {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You have a mapping method that takes anything that implements an INamed and kicks out an object with the Name set:

```
SomeDto Map(INamed x){
  return new SomeDto { Name = x.Name }
}
```

And you call it appropriately:

```
context.Persons.Select(person => Map(person) );

context.Companies.Select(company => Map(company) );
```

Comment: Note; objects have been simplified for clarity of demonstrating the point